# precondition failure: invalid input index when using GeometryReader in SwiftUI starting with iOS 13.4

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, combine

Yesterday I upgraded XCode and my project to iOS 13.4 and I started to see a lot of failures in  around views that use GeometryReaders.

The error does not reveal anything besides "precondition failure: invalid input index"

Comment: Suffered the same issue. Removing the parent NavigationView solved the issue in my case (I didn't need it), but this may not be a suitable solution for all.

Comment: Also seeing this. This update is killing me :(

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue after upgrading to 13.4.1.

I installed a simulator with 13.3.3 and it didn't have the issue.

What ended up causing the issue was having a GeometryReader as an inner view of a NavigationView. Making the GeometryReader the top-most view fixed it for me.

Comment: This answer might be a nice temporary fix to get going again, but if this is indeed the issue this seems like a critical bug. Not being able to (consistently) use GeometryReader inside a NavigationView is a gamebreaker!

Answer (score 0):

After debugging and starting to lose my mind, I found that each view that had a GeometryReader also was using onReceive with a call to a function that had Combine code.

Basically I was calling .collect() on the Publisher and sink-ing the result to a variable.

After I removed the Combine code and started to use old fashioned array operations, all started working again.

Comment: hi Andrei, the latest update has also broken my Watch app that uses SwiftUI. I use GeometryReader to read the size of the screen so I can draw a frame in a size relative to the screen size. So I using geometry.size.width and geometry.size.height, I get precondition failure: invalid input index: 2. I seem to think it relates to the height, but I'm not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Do you use Combine in any way? I also was suspecting geometry.size.height but after removing all the Combine code, it started working again

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same problem as @alamodey.
Has anyone managed to reproduce this in a sample project?  This doesn't seem like expected behaviour at all

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Any solution ?

Comment: @alamodey my crash is only appearing in simulator.  It runs fine on device, except (oddly) when running the app using the VoiceOver accessibility feature

Comment: @JoeySlomowitz you are right, the app doesn't crash on device but it does in simulator. Carry on!