# SwiftUI - StackNavigationStyle() causing precondition failure: invalid index 2

Tags: swiftui, ios13

I have a project with 4 main views. Here is the body of the ContentView containing the NavigationView. I added the modifier **.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())** so I don't get the split view navigation in landscape mode.

ContentView.swift:

```
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                Text("Scoreboard")
                .font(.custom("Chalkduster", size: 50))
                
                Button(action: {
                    self.new_game = true
                }) {
                    Text("New Game")
                    .font(.custom("Chalkduster", size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                
                NavigationLink(destination: CreateGameView(TEST_NAV: self.$new_game), isActive: $new_game) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
                //.isDetailLink(false)
            }
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
```

This is causing my app to crash under certain circumstances and I'm not sure why. It is also caused if I remove this line but add the **.isDetailLink(false)** to every NavigationLink (I have one on ContentView.swift, CreateGameView.swift, and GameView.swift). I am not sure how to show the issue succinctly with a few code snippets so I think the best way is to provide the entire project with the steps to recreate the crash. Here is the github for the project: https://github.com/steve3424/scoreboard_project

**To recreate crash:**

1. Start the simulator.
2. Click "New Game".
3. Add any title and at least one player.
4. Start game.
5. Do 1 of 2 things:

   - Long tap the "Round 1" label to bring up context menu (This will cause what I think is a warning "unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints". I don't think this is a problem though)
   - Click and drag the "Round 1" label to up or down
6. Navigate back and the app will crash with "precondition failure: invalid index 2". A **SIGABRT** happens on line 65 of GameView.swift.

From what I have read:

[precondition failure: invalid input index when using GeometryReader in SwiftUI starting with iOS 13.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60868788/precondition-failure-invalid-input-index-when-using-geometryreader-in-swiftui-s)

[How to debug "precondition failure" in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58304009/how-to-debug-precondition-failure-in-xcode)

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/eis04m/precondition_failure_invalid_input_index/

I think it has something to do with the GeometryReader. The only place I use GeometryReader is here:

GameView.swift line 29:

```
struct TrackableScrollView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    let axes: Axis.Set
    let showIndicators: Bool
    @Binding var contentOffset: CGFloat
    let content: Content
    
    init(_ axes: Axis.Set = .vertical, showIndicators: Bool = true, contentOffset: Binding<CGFloat>, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.axes = axes
        self.showIndicators = showIndicators
        self._contentOffset = contentOffset
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { outsideProxy in
            ScrollView(self.axes, showsIndicators: self.showIndicators) {
                ZStack(alignment: self.axes == .vertical ? .top : .leading) {
                    GeometryReader { insideProxy in
                        Color.clear
                            .preference(key: ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: [self.calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy: outsideProxy, insideProxy: insideProxy)])
                            // Send value to the parent
                    }
                    VStack {
                        self.content
                    }
                }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(ScrollOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                self.contentOffset = value[0]
            }
            // Get the value then assign to offset binding
        }
    }
    
    private func calculateContentOffset(fromOutsideProxy outsideProxy: GeometryProxy, insideProxy: GeometryProxy) -> CGFloat {
        if axes == .vertical {
            return (insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY - outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minY)
        } else {
            return (insideProxy.frame(in: .global).minX - outsideProxy.frame(in: .global).minX)
        }
    }
}
```

Above is a trackable scrollview created here: https://medium.com/@maxnatchanon/swiftui-how-to-get-content-offset-from-scrollview-5ce1f84603ec

It allows me to get the scroll offset from both the vertical and horizontal scrollviews and match the movement of the main grid.

Now comment out the **.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())** found in the ContentView.swift (shown above). Repeat the steps and the crash should not happen. This is the only thing I have found that fixes the crash.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is there a way to fix this crash without removing **.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())**?